# How to achieve diagonal two-color fill

Tags: svg

I'm trying to fill a rounded-corner rectangle, with two colours, one colour either side of a diagonal line across the corners.

I've tried adding a triangular filled polygon, but this shows through the parent rectangle transparent corners.

So I've tried using a pattern, which is *almost* working.

The issue is that the pattern seems to be starting at co-ords 0,0 of the entire SGV, not the shape it's filling.

Example here:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" version="1.1" width="800" height="800">
  <defs>
    <pattern x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="SvgjsPattern1008">
      <polygon points="0,0 100,100 0,100" fill="#ff00ff" stroke-width="1" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox"/>
      <polygon points="0,0 100,0 100,100" fill="#00ff00" stroke-width="1" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100" height="100" x="0" y="75" rx="20" ry="20" fill="url(&quot;#SvgjsPattern1008&quot;)"/>
</svg>
```

How can I get it so the pattern starts in the top-left corner of the rectangle?

Also, I'm looking for a pure SVG solution, no CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Use an appropriately defined gradient to fill it:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" version="1.1" width="800" height="800">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="diagonal" x1="0%" x2="100%" y1="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="purple" />
      <stop offset="50%"  stop-color="purple" />
      <stop offset="50%"  stop-color="green" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="green" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100" height="100" x="0" y="75" rx="20" ry="20" fill="url(#diagonal)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is to convert to objectBoundingBox units - they run from 0 to 1 and are relative to the shape's position.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" version="1.1" width="800" height="800">
  <defs>
    <pattern x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="SvgjsPattern1008">
      <polygon points="0,0 1,1 0,1" fill="#ff00ff" stroke-width="1" />
      <polygon points="0,0 1,0 1,1" fill="#00ff00" stroke-width="1" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100" height="100" x="0" y="75" rx="20" ry="20" fill="url(&quot;#SvgjsPattern1008&quot;)"/>
</svg>
```